# sharepoint designer can not display the item for list workflows

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When I tried to access the existign list work flows in the sp designer 2010, I am getting the below error message.

SharePoint designer can not display the item.

Even, I tried to open the OOB approval workflow or collect signatures workflows, I am getting the same error message.

Even,I tried creating new workflow with associating to lists, it was not showing any thing.

Please help on the issue.